# Very slow exploring ASP.NET application at second floor company

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, client-server

I designed an ASP application for travel company. I'll summarize my problem as points:
1- create the system using aspnet technique.
2- using core i7 lenovo Labtop to be a server
3- using Windows 7 as operating system.
4- using router to enable other computers to access remotely to the application
5- the computers at the first floor are connected easily
6- the computers at the second floor have difficult to access the application

I'll appreciate anyone specify the problem and give the solution.

Comment: Does your second floor have different permissions than your department, on the network?

Comment: Both floors have same permissions. The procedure is any computer need to access to the system, just connect at the same ssid that the server is connected. This procedure is ok at the 1st floor but badly connected as 2nd floor

Answer (score 0):

You can add on the second floor a repeater to the first floor router, and connect the repeater to the router via an Ethernet cable, this way you will no longer have security issues on the second floor!

Comment: I understand from your answer using two routers and one repeater. The first router at the first floor and repeater at second floor that connect to second router at second floor also. If that is what you mentioned why I should use second router at 2nd floor? instead, I just based on repeater?

Comment: No i mean just one router on the first floor and one repeater on the second floor, and connect the second floor repeater to the first floor router !
the first floor router will give IP's to the second floor.. this way they will have exactly the same access to the network .

Comment: it's preferable to connect the repeater to the router via an Ethernet cable